# Can PHP detect if Apache has been restarted?

Tags: php, linux, apache

Not sure if this is even possible but let's say I run `sudo service apache2 restart`. Can PHP detect that Apache has restarted? I know it can do error handling if there's a fatal error https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php#92810 but I'm stumped on whether or not PHP can tell if Apache has restarted. Thanks!

Comment: Not innately, no, but there are a number of ways you could kinda fake it. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: something similar to `register_shutdown_function` would be great...like `register_apache_restart_function`

Comment: You can't do that from within a PHP script that Apache itself is running, you're probably better off having the Apache restart script itself trigger the required functionality.

Comment: Sounds like a job for another script or language away from Apache and PHP, which monitors and/or creates a log when Apache starts up and PHP can hook into that once it's restarted again.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2):

You could look at the file modified time of the `httpd.pid` file using `filemtime`.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a CRON job running every minute to read the logs of httpd found under `/var/log/httpd/error_log` (or similar). Then complete a regex check for 
`-- resuming normal operations` in the log file, pull each item's datetime and compare it with the current datetime.